# Can PHP array passed POST method to catch in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

Can PHP array passed POST method to catch in ASP.NET MVC?

Query string: WebAccess/ArrayTest?val[]=1&val[]=2&val[]=3

I write: ActionResult ArrayTest (String[] val)

But this only works if the query string to remove the "[]"

Comment: I for one, and most likely alot of other users have no clue what you are trying to achieve. POST doesn't work through querystring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in DefaultModelBinder in ASP.NET MVC can't handle rails/php/jquery1.4 style array posts (which is what you're referring to with val[]=1&val[]=2&val[]=3).

You have to either create a custom modelbinder (google it, lots of examples) or adding indices inside the bracket like so:

```
val[0]=1&val[1]=2&val[2]=3
```

And the indices must not have any missing numbers.

I have fixed this with a script that on submit of the form just adds the indices. i.e. in jQuery:

```
$('form').find('input, select, textarea').attr('name', function(index, old) {
    return old.replace(/\[\]/, '[' + index + ']');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(not an answer - but its difficult to explain this using a S.O. comment)

You've rather confused things by suggesting that this is really anything to do with PHP. Also, you don't say which '[]' you removed to make it work. The unenlightened asp programmers out there might find it easier to understand:

```
<form method='POST' action='something.asp'>
   <input type='text' name='val[]'>
   <input type='text' name='val[]'>
   <input type='text' name='val[]'>
   <input type='submit' value='go'>
</form>
```

Using **some web development languages** the data from each the three text fields is subsequently available in an array named 'val'. How to replicate this behaviour in asp.net?

C.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class PhpStyleArrayBinder : DefaultModelBinder,IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName+"[]");
            if (val != null)
                return val;
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
public JsonResult Get([ModelBinder(typeof (PhpStyleArrayBinder))] IEnumerable<string> data)
        {
            //
        }
```

http://pavelsvetlov.blogspot.com/2016/04/mvcnet-modelbinder-phpstyle-array.html